# JSF h:selectOneMenu trouble: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Cannot convert "string" of type class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List

Tags: java, jsf, selectonemenu

I have some JSF-trouble using h:selectOneMenu with a list from my backend bean:
My xhtml file looks like this:

```
  <f:view>
    <h:form id="serverOptions">
      <h:selectOneMenu id="preset" value="#{overview.pdfPresets}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{overview.pdfPresets}" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
      <h:commandButton action="submit" value="Submit" />
    </h:form>
  </f:view>
```

where the corresponding managing bean looks like this:

```
private List<String> pdfPresets;
private String pdfPreset;

/**
 * Returns a list of pdfPresets
 * @return a List<String> of pdf preset names
 */
public final List<String> getPdfPresets() {
    return pdfPresets;
}

/**
 * Sets the name of the selected pdfPreset
 * (trying to overload setPdfPresets here)
 * @param presetName
 * @see setPdfPreset
 */
public final void setPdfPresets(String presetName) {
    // write preset name somehwere else
    this.presetName = presetName;
}

/**
 * Sets the pdfPresets
 * @param list
 */
public final void setPdfPresets(List<String> list) {
    pdfPresets = list;
}
```

The problem occurs on submitting the form in my browser, the full error stack looks like this:

```
EVERE: An exception occurred
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert screen_druckbogen of type class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:398)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:299)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:187)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._processUpdatesDefault(UIViewRoot.java:1317)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.access$600(UIViewRoot.java:75)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$UpdateModelPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1419)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1278)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:761)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesExecutor.execute(UpdateModelValuesExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert screen_druckbogen of type class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:397)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:164)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:380)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: `setPdfPresets(String presetName)` is not a good idea, you should only have setters and getters of coherent types; also despite what your comment suggests that's not overloading.

Comment: Using an additional setter for String was only a test, trying to write the returned string into a separate property. Unluckily it did not work.

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[selectonemenu]` tag which you put on the question yourself and click *info* link on the popbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <f:view>
    <h:form id="serverOptions">
      <h:selectOneMenu id="preset" value="#{overview.pdfPreset}" > <!-- typo here -->
        <f:selectItems value="#{overview.pdfPresets}" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
      <h:commandButton action="submit" value="Submit" />
    </h:form>
  </f:view>
```

where the corresponding managing bean looks like this:

```
private List<String> pdfPresets;
private String pdfPreset;

/**
 * Returns a list of pdfPresets
 * @return a List<String> of pdf preset names
 */
public final List<String> getPdfPresets() {
    return pdfPresets;
}

/**
 * Sets the name of the selected pdfPreset
 * (trying to overload setPdfPresets here)
 * @param presetName
 * @see setPdfPreset
 */
public final void setPdfPreset(String presetName) { //renamed method
    // write preset name somehwere else
    pdfPreset = presetName; //use the correct variable
}

/**
 * Sets the pdfPresets
 * @param list
 */
public final void setPdfPresets(List<String> list) {
    pdfPresets = list;
}
```

Comment: Damnit, you are right. I missed the typo for a few hours. My setter/getter for PdfPreset existed already, I'm simply let 'em out since I thought the error located in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Your value attribute needs to be a `String` instead of a `List<String>` because it will hold the selection. And your bean is not really a bean since it needs unique setters for the fields in order to be processed by JSF.

So you should change your bean code in a way that it has a `List<String>` with getters and setters and a `String` for the selection with *separate* getters and setters:

```java
private List<String> pdfPresets;
private String selectedPdfPreset;

public List<String> getPdfPresets() {
  return pdfPresets;
}

public void setPdfPresets(List<String> pdfPresets) {
  this.pdfPresets = pdfPresets;
}

public String getSelectedPdfPreset() {
  return selectedPdfPreset;
}

public void setSelectedPdfPreset(String selectedPdfPreset) {
  this.selectedPdfPreset = selectedPdfPreset;
}
```

And in the view:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="preset" value="#{overview.selectedPdfPreset}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{overview.pdfPresets}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, what to do. Can you supply me some code?

Comment: Many thanks, looks like I've been missing some serious typo in my original h:selectOneMenu.